# Rename files to new naming convention in bash

Tags: bash, awk, rename

I have a directory of files with names formatted like

```
01-Peterson@2x.png
15-Consolidated@2x.png
03-Brady@2x.png
```

And I would like to format them like

```
PETERSON.png
CONSOLIDATED.png
BRADY.png
```

But my bash scripting skills are pretty weak right now. What is the best way to go about this?

Edit: my bash version is 3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: Have a look at the perl `rename` tool.

Comment: You should improve your question a little bit, like adding more file names to confirm the pattern, as well as providing your bash version (`echo $BASH_VERSION`)

Comment: @Socowi I don't appear to have rename on my machine `-bash: rename: command not found`

Comment: @AlexandreJuma Thanks for the advice! I edited the original question with that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pattern for all your files are like the one you posted, I'd say you can do something as simple as running this on your directory:

```
for file in `ls *.png`; do new_file=`echo $file | awk -F"-" '{print $2}' | awk -F"@" '{n=split($2,a,"."); print toupper($1) "." a[2]}'`; mv $file $new_file; done
```

If you fancy learning other solutions, like regexes, you can also do:

```
for file in `ls *.png`; do new_file=`echo $file | sed "s/.*-//g;s/@.*\././g" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`; mv $file $new_file; done
```

Testing it, it does for example:

```
mv 01-Peterson@2x.png PETERSON.png
mv 02-Bradley@2x.png BRADLEY.png
mv 03-Jacobs@2x.png JACOBS.png
mv 04-Matts@1x.png MATTS.png
mv 05-Jackson@4x.png JACKSON.png
```

Comment: That worked! I just used your first example. Thank you for your help. I'm going to spend some time learning the `awk` tool.

From what I can tell your solution uses `awk`'s `-F` flag is for field separation so it's doing a split on the string. I'm a little lost on the specifics of the second call (like where the `a` comes from), but it looks like it's getting the file extension and appending it to the uppercase filename. 

Anyway it looks great thanks again for your help!

Comment: It's something like this: The first awk will only remove the first "01-", the second will split by "@" and keep in a the last item of a string splited by the ".", which in fact is the file extension. Then it extracts the filename (which is the 1st item when splitting by "@") and concatenates it to the file extension.

Comment: This answer contains multiple anit-patterns including looping on the output of `ls` rather than just globbing, using `for file in` rather than `while read file`, using deprecated backticks instead of `$(...)`, unquoted variables like `$file` instead of `"$file"`, moving a file even if the preceding command failed, and it calls multiple tools when one would do. Don't do it...

Answer (score 3):

This will work for files that contains spaces (including newlines), backslashes, or any other character, including globbing chars that could cause a false match on other files in the directory, and it won't remove your home file system given a particularly undesirable file name!

```
for old in *.png; do
    new=$(
        awk 'BEGIN {
                base = sfx = ARGV[1]
                sub(/^.*\./,"",sfx)
                sub(/^[^-]+-/,"",base)
                sub(/@[^@.]+\.[^.]+$/,"",base)
                print toupper(base) "." sfx
                exit
            }' "$old"
        ) &&
    mv -- "$old" "$new"
done
```